# How to speed up sql queries ? Indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization

I have the following database structure :

```
create table Accounting
(
  Channel,
  Account
)

create table ChannelMapper
(
  AccountingChannel,
  ShipmentsMarketPlace,
  ShipmentsChannel
)

create table AccountMapper
(
  AccountingAccount,
  ShipmentsComponent
)

create table Shipments
(
   MarketPlace,
   Component,
   ProductGroup,
   ShipmentChannel,
   Amount
 )
```

I have the following query running on these tables and I'm trying to optimize the query to run as fast as possible :

```
 select Accounting.Channel, Accounting.Account, Shipments.MarketPlace
 from Accounting join ChannelMapper on Accounting.Channel = ChannelMapper.AccountingChannel

 join AccountMapper on Accounting.Accounting = ChannelMapper.AccountingAccount
 join Shipments on 
 (
     ChannelMapper.ShipmentsMarketPlace = Shipments.MarketPlace
     and ChannelMapper.AccountingChannel = Shipments.ShipmentChannel
     and AccountMapper.ShipmentsComponent = Shipments.Component
 )
 join (select Component, sum(amount) from Shipment group by component) as Totals
    on  Shipment.Component = Totals.Component
```

How do I make this query run as fast as possible ? Should I use indexes ? If so, which columns of which tables should I index ?

Here is a picture of my query plan :

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Indexes are essential. Anything in a `WHERE` clause is a candidate for indexing. Can you post the actual schema instead of your abstract version?

Comment: Data modelling is crucial. First: add some real types (possibly domains) to your columns. Second: PK/FK constraints are elementary. Third: (as a rule of thumb) if tables appear to have more than two candidate keys, they are suspect. Your channelmapper and shipments tables _could_ suffer from this phenomenon (could be BCNF or 4NF vioalations), but you did not show any candidate keys, and even the semantics are fuzzy.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Indexes are essential to any database.

Speaking in "layman" terms, indexes are... well, precisely that. You can think of an index as a second, hidden, table that stores two things: The sorted data and a pointer to its position in the table.

Some thumb rules on creating indexes:

1. Create indexes on every field that is (or will be) used in joins.
2. Create indexes on every field on which you want to perform frequent `where` conditions.
3. Avoid creating indexes on everything. Create index on the relevant fields of every table, and use relations to retrieve the desired data.
4. Avoid creating indexes on `double` fields, unless it is absolutely necessary.
5. Avoid creating indexes on `varchar` fields, unless it is absolutely necesary.

I recommend you to read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html

Comment: Indexes on doubles and varchars are fine when they're relevant. We're in 2013, not the 1980s.

Comment: @Denis It's a good point. I avoid them because I am generally able to use other indexed fields, and get the same results. (By the way, I am not *that* old ;-) )

Answer (score 3):

Your JOINS should be the first place to look. The two most obvious candidates for indexes are `AccountMapper.AccountingAccount` and `ChannelMapper.AccountingChannel`.

You should consider indexing `Shipments.MarketPlace`,`Shipments.ShipmentChannel` and `Shipments.Component` as well.

However, adding indexes increases the workload in maintaining them. While they might give you a performance boost on this query, you might find that updating the tables becomes unacceptably slow. In any case, the MySQL optimiser might decide that a full scan of the table is quicker than accessing it by index.

Really the only way to do this is to set up the indexes that would appear to give you the best result and then benchmark the system to make sure you're getting the results you want here, whilst not compromising the performance elsewhere. Make good use of the [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) statement to find out what's going on, and remember that optimisations made by yourself or the optimiser on small tables may not be the same optimisations you'd need on larger ones.

Answer (score 2):

The other three answers seem to have indexes covered so this is in addition to indexes.  You have no where clause which means you are always selecting the whole darn database.  In fact, your database design doesn't have anything useful in this regard, such as a shipping date.  Think about that.

You also have this:

```
join (select Component, sum(amount) from Shipment group by component) as Totals
on  Shipment.Component = Totals.Component
```

That's all well and good but you don't select anything from this subquery.  Therefore why do you have it?  If you did want to select something, such as the sum(amount), you will have to give that an alias to make it available in the select clause.