# Selecting all unique records from 1.5million row table with 50 columns

Tags: mysql

I need to select all unique records from a 1.5million row table with 50 columns and put them in another table, I havent added any sort of index yet, is there a better way than:

```
INSERT INTO `unique` SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `allData`
```

I just started this query in phpmyadmin but I think that may be the wrong way to go about it? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Define "unique". Are 2 rows equal because ALL 50 columns are equal?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I mean!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If your table does not have any indexes, you are in for a big load of pain.
2. Do you really need to find duplicates in all 50 columns? Consider getting only the data that you really need.
3. **Add the appropriate indexes**. I can't stress this point enough. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354219/how-to-speed-up-sql-queries-indexes/17354616#17354616).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I need to keep all 50 columns before normalising after. Do you have any steps (ie what key to use?) / a query example to check for duplicate rows?

Comment: If you really need to deduplicate the 50 columns, and they are not indexed, and you can't normalize that table, then do exactly what you wrote (`select distinct...`) and get a nice cup of coffee ;) I think you should try to normalize the table *before* trying to deduplicate it... it can save you lots and lots of pain.

Comment: +1 the `SELECT DISTINCT` solution is the only option, because MySQL indexes cannot have more than 16 columns.