# how to speed up my query in sql

Tags: sql, performance, view

I create 2 views where the first view gets the details of the asset and other views count the audited asset. I combine the two views to create the main view report but my problem it takes 5 minutes to generate the data and cause timeout error in my application. Can I use the index to speed up my query or do have a trick you use to speed up your query?

Comment: What do the tables and queries look like?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use index in uniq fields. While you are joining the tables, you can add more filtres. You can check your join parameters. Actually, it depends on your database and views.

Also you can search it in this site : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html

İt is a special example for you. You can learn this topic with this link:
[How to speed up sql queries ? Indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354219/how-to-speed-up-sql-queries-indexes)